# What does the ? mean in a downcast in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In the line:

```
 let x = cat.nameOfCat as? String
```

Does the `?` after `as` mean that the downcast String is optional because if the casting fails, you'll end up with `nil`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 'as?' if the object can't be cast, then it returns nil, while with 'as', if the object can't be cast than it crashes.

Use the ? form unless you're very sure that the cast is valid, in which case you can drop it to avoid dealing with the unnecessary optional.

Comment: Assertion failure. Right now that's uncatchable; I'd imagine (though I don't know) that when Swift gets some sort of error handling model it might be.

Comment: @JayO'Conor a crash is when the program runs into a fatal error and it can no longer run and is shutdown unplaned.

Comment: I suspect Jay was asking whether it's the "undefined behavior, blow up in possibly exploitable ways" type of crash like many memory errors in C, vs a controlled diagnostic crash.